# getElementById().value gives value when text box is empty

Tags: javascript, html

This problem is really giving headache to me. Due to some reasons I can't post the code here, so please give a solution by just going through my problem.

In my java script there is a document.getElementById("txtBoxId").value statement that reads  text box value.The problem is the statement gives  value(the value is not just blank spaces it is actually some text that exists on some part of the page ) even if the text box is empty. I have given the id of text box in the statement and no other element has the same id,still statement is returning value. Please help me to find an answer

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by not posting the code here? It is almost impossible for any of us to help you now.

Comment: " This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself."

Comment: It is completely impossible to figure out whats going on without a code example that reproduces the behaviour.

Comment: We don't need *your actual* code, we need some code that is testable, minimal and reproduces your problem.

Comment: are you sure you are looking at the element at the right time? Also, are you sure you are looking at the right element? Duplicate IDs may be hard to spot.

Comment: Also, are you sure the element is acually empty? Just because it's not visible and it starts empty, doesn't mean it actually is empty. Autocomplete may do wonders to your forms.

Comment: Also, what _is_ the value? If it's `"[object HTMLInputElement]"`, this might give away the reason.

Comment: Is the `textarea` tag closed? `textarea`s are not self-closing elements...

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code all I can say is:

Either there's still an element on the page with that id or the txtBox in question has a default value applied.

Comment: The default value of a textarea is its initial content (i.e. its initial textContent), it doesn't have a value attribute (thought it does have a value property).

Comment: I assumed user3127042 meant a text input when he said "text box" which can have a value attr hardcoded or added programatically. Again, me no see code, me no get everything right.